# br tag is not working while replace the content from textarea to DIV using JQUERY text function

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

The br tag is not working on DIV.
I am getting the message from Update Content: `textarea`field.
The message have the 2 lines like "Rama" next line "Lingam".
But the result is "Rama
Lingam" by  `$("#editQuotesRowLabel_Q_013").text(replaceContent);`

How to make a new line in DIV?

**Here is my code:**

```
function updateQuotes(){    
    var weg_quotes = $("#weg_quotes_Q_013").val();  
    replaceContent = weg_quotes.replace("\n", "<br>", "g");         
    $("#editQuotesRowLabel_Q_013").text(replaceContent);
}
```

```html
Update Content: <textarea placeholder="Update your content..." id="weg_quotes_Q_013" name="weg_quotes" cols="80" rows="3" class="appQuotesTextarea" maxlength="200" required=""></textarea>
<button onclick="updateQuotes()" id="Q_013" name="update-btn" class="appQuotesBtn">Update</button>

<div id="editQuotesRowLabel_Q_013" class="appQuotesLabel">
    This is content div. 
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To insert HTML content using jquery you need to use  `.html()` instead of `.text()`.
So in your case you end up with :

```
 $("#editQuotesRowLabel_Q_013").html(replaceContent);
 //                              |_ use html() instead of text()
```

Source :

- [.html()](http://api.jquery.com/html/)
- [.text()](http://api.jquery.com/text/)

Comment: It's  Working fine..Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

Just use `.html()` instead of `.text()` because textarea content will also contain 
 tags and `.html()` can show html also, `.text()` will only consider text -  it will not set html tags (
 tag here) in div, so use `.html()` instead of `.text()`

```js
function updateQuotes(obj){ 
    var weg_quotes = $("#weg_quotes_Q_013").val();  
    replaceContent = weg_quotes.replace("\n", "<br>", "g");   
    $("#editQuotesRowLabel_Q_013").html(replaceContent);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
Update Content: <textarea placeholder="Update your content..." id="weg_quotes_Q_013" name="weg_quotes" cols="80" rows="3" class="appQuotesTextarea" maxlength="200" required=""></textarea>
<button onclick="updateQuotes(this)" id="Q_013" name="update-btn" class="appQuotesBtn">Update</button>

<div id="editQuotesRowLabel_Q_013" class="appQuotesLabel">
    This is content div. 
</div>
```

Comment: It's  Working fine..Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Try with this:

```
$("#editQuotesRowLabel_Q_013").html(replaceContent);
```

// Try to use `html()` instead of `text()`

This will allow you to use html tags :)

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure what that replace() method is, but it replace is

```
str.replace(pattern/string, function/replacement)
```

So your code should be

```
replaceContent = weg_quotes.replace(/\n/g, "<br>");
```

and you should be using `.html()` when you are inserting html into a div.

```
$("#editQuotesRowLabel_Q_013").html(replaceContent);
```

Comment: It's  Working fine..Thanks!

Comment: @RamaLingam FYI, hopefully you followed my advice on changing the replace() line... Only reason you are not seeing an issue is the fact you only have one replacement. If you had two, all the other answers would fail.

Answer (score 1):

*Try this one `.html()` instead of `.text()`*

```
$("#editQuotesRowLabel_Q_013").html(replaceContent);
```